# Can a branch be made from a previous changeset?

Tags: tfs, branch

I need to create a branch at a specific Changeset in TFS.  Is this doable?

For example, I have changeset 1528 that was the last check in on my project.  But I want to branch from changeset 1487.  Can this be done?

If so, how?

Note: I am using TFS 2008

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes. When a branch is created you can choose the historical point in time when it takes effect (date, changeset, etc).

See [Visual Studio TFS Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) for some great information on recommended branching practices.

Or [How to: Branch Files and Folders (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425(v=VS.80).aspx) for more explicit instructions on getting this dialog up to create a branch.

Comment: @Imran Rizvi: Thanks! I've found the new location and updated the link.

Comment: thanks, this helped with with half of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969773/create-branch-at-specific-change-set-move-changests-after-this-point-to-differe - but how do i reset the parent branch ??

Answer (score 22):

Visual Studio 2010 and later added support for this functionality:

[image: Branch dialog]