# TFS Process flow for fixing bug in older version

Tags: visual-studio-2012, shelveset

**Scenario:**

I have a bug to fix in changeset 100. We currently have 125 changesets. I also am in the middle of some large changes. We have a production bug to fix.

**Requirement**

1. To put my current changes on hold
2. pull up the code from changeset 100 (the current production code
       base)
3. Fix the bug. Recompile. Deploy.
4. Resume my work from point 1. And also ensure it includes the bug fix.

**Presumed Process Flow**

5. Shelve Pending Changes to server (not locally...just to make sure the changes are safe.
6. Source Control > Get Specific Version and get change set 100
7. Fix the bug....now I'm not sure of next steps..
8. Check in; unshelve? OR
9. Check in; Get Latest (which will bring me up to the last change set 125) , then unshelve?

And how does the fixed bug code get merged in?

Comment: Are you maintaining an integration branch as well as a dev branch or do you have only one branch. Typically you would make your release branches off of your integration branch (only QAed code in there). The release branch would actually be two branches: a service pack branch created off the integration branch and then a read only release branch off of that. When bugs happen in the release you fix them in the SP branch and then cut a new release branch off of that. Then, when ready, you merge your sp bug fixes (after testing) back through integration and into your dev branch.

Comment: Also, to my knowledge changesets are always stored on the server.

Comment: @MikeCheel Thanks for the insight Mike. To answer your question, as of today, we only have a single branch.

Comment: If you labeled your release you can branch from the label using the mechanism I described in my first comment and make that your release branch that allows you fix it. Then should be able to follow the rest of the pattern I described. I have always set it up the way I describe and have never relied on a singe branch but I think I am telling you should work. Also, if you are using TFS for your build system TFS creates a label for each build so you should have that. Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761394/can-a-branch-be-made-from-a-previous-changeset

Comment: Thanks @MikeCheel I will research this some more. Seems like we definitely want to branch when we publish to Production. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what you end up doing. Also check out the alm rangers guides. Good luck