# Create branch at specific change set, move changests after this point to different branch

Tags: tfs, branch, alm

*Hypothetical scenario:*
By mistake, I've been working away on my 'Main' branch.

What I need to do, is effectively reset my Main branch to a particular  changeset - 1001 for example.
Changesets after 1001, I want to move to a new branch - 'Dev'

Is this possible?

I come from a git background, so if this were a git repository, I would probably use something like:

```
git checkout -b Dev 1001  //create branch at 1001
git checkout Main  //back on Main
git reset --hard 1000  //reset main to 1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in the server based source control world.

I would recommend that you take a copy of your code, and roll back the change.

Then create a branch and overwrite the changes that you copied. Dirty, but works...

Solution: Use git

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird - On my Main branch, I branched at changeset 1001. Then I rolled back main - this *looks* like it's worked...?

Comment: ps. Using git would be my preference, however this place is head over heels in love with TFS (albeit with nobody that can use it / administer it....)

Comment: If you rolled back Main then that change cs1003, will overwrite what you have in the branch when you merge.

Comment: Current changeset was 1051. I right clicked Main - Create Branch - Branch from Version - cs1001. Called this 'Dev' I then rolled back Main to 1001. Main is now 1001. Dev is 1051... so if i work on Dev, then merge back into Main, is it still going to be overwritten?

Comment: I am not at all sure of that @Alex ... you will need to poke around and see if it works. That's a Git workflow and I have never used it on TFVC.